# How to manipulate tuple argument in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

New to Ocaml, need help manipulating tuple arguments

The function takes in an argument of 3 integers and returns the reverse of it

Example: rev (5, 8, 6) = (6, 8, 5)
rev (3, 2, 1) = (1, 2, 3)

Comment: One doesn't *manipulate* a tuple. One creates a new one.

Comment: @Bergi, "manipulate" doesn't necessarily mean "mutate". It's actually a formulation you'll often find in formal literature to denote any form of creation, access, processing of some category of data objects.

Answer (score 5):

The way to access elements of a tuple in OCaml is by pattern matching.

For simple types, in fact, the pattern can appear in the place where the function argument goes.

Your function takes a 3-tuple, so it could look something like this:

```
let myfun (a, b, c) =
    (* rest of function goes here *)
```

The `(a, b, c)` is a pattern that will match the individual elements of the tuple passed to the function.

It shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to complete the function, but don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: +1                                                                         for posting an answer, not a solution